Handling Failure and Resume Processing in Django
I have task to create routes. A route can be an object with origin, destination, type.
Origin and Destination are just a FK from Location ojbect.
Imagine I have 3 Locations, a, b, c. with three types, X, Y, Z. Then possible routes are.
routes = [(a,b,x), (a,c,x), (b,a, x), (b,c,x), (c, a, x), (c, b, x) , (a,b,y), (a,c,y), (b,a, y), (b,c,y), (c, a, y), (c, b, y) , (a,b,z), (a,c,z), (b,a, z), (b,c,z), (c, a, z), (c, b, z) ]

Now, Im able to create the routes with same output. but the problem I'm going to have more than 43 thousands unique locations, on estimation it is going to be around 5.5B unique routes based on 3 types. So I wanted to have a different type approach where I can resume the process if something fails. we don't have problem if this takes days, but there will be a problem if we are starting it from Zero again if something fails.
So any idea or concept would be appreciated. We are using Django application to handle this. here's the real Models and Code. Im planning to use this create_route functions in the background with the help of celery and redis.
class Route(models.Model):
    origin = models.ForeignKey(
        Location, related_name="route_origin", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    destination = models.ForeignKey(
        Location, related_name="route_destination", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    # Type options
    VAN, REEFER, FLATBED = "V", "R", "F"

    equipment_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        choices=(
            (VAN, "Van"),
            (REEFER, "Reefer"),
            (FLATBED, "Flatbed"),
        ),
    )



class Location(models.Model):
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=5)


def create_routes():
    locations = Location.objects.all()
        equipment_types = [Route.VAN, Route.REEFER, Route.FLATBED]
        for origin, destination in permutations(locations, 2):
            for equipment_type in equipment_types:
                Route.objects.create(
                    origin=origin,
                    destination=destination,
                    equipment_type=equipment_type,
                )


I'm open to change the model structure if that helps...

Do you actually need to have 5.5 billion concrete rows in the database? (Sounds a bit absurd to me.) What would you plan to use these routes for?

We are going to create Carriers that will have M2M relationship with routes. In the end we are going to have Search Portal, where user can provide origin, destination, type and we will return Carriers against that input.

Open to any other better idea, that can avoid creation of these rows and still we can achieve this functionality in the end.

Then only create the routes that those carriers actually have, instead of pre-creating everything?

IOW, have the Route model be unique_together over its three fields, and when a carrier (somehow) registers they're able to do a X to Y with equipment Z route, get_or_create(from=X, to=Y, equipment=Z) that route, and hook the carrier up to that object.

This seems right, but still it's going to be a longer task, because the data we will recieve from a thirdparty, whose API accepts origin, destination, type and returns all of the carrier against it, So for that we still are going to process the Routes anyway.

Sure, but that's presumably a lot less than 5.5 billion rows.

Also – that third party will likely not be very happy if you do 5.5 billion calls to their API anyway, so you might want to reconsider that approach to begin with. (And if one API call takes 0.1 seconds, you'd still be looking at 3.1 years to finish getting that information.)

Any idea about handling the fail and resume process if we are really going to initiate this long task ? @AKX

I would really, really advise you not to do that in the first place, and to reconsider your requirements. But if you will, then, well, given an index i of things you have done, you can use divmod() thrice to figure out which from, to, and equipment corresponds to that index (just like you can tell from the number of seconds passed in a day which hour, minute and second it is).

You will be wasting your time in the end if you do not redesign as early as now.

Thanks all of you, one mistake was to target zipcodes because each city has around more than 100 Zipcodes and data for carriers between these zipcodes was common, now we will use the cities instead of Zipcodes as unqiue location, and it will reduce the processing time.... Thanks guys your persistent guidance to look for any other strucutre. We will try to find more mistakes and will try to restructure first.
